# SQL Server: deterministic columns and resulting view performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with constantly updating 30 second weather data. The data from my weather sensor eventually ends up in the SQL Server with a timestamp in UTC.

I want to be able to summarize this high frequency data in a `DailySummary` table, however I want the days to represent my local timezone (Central Standard Time) not UTC. I've added a computed column to my high frequency table for local time to aid in this:

```
((([TmStamp] AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'))
```

As it stands, I cannot make this a `PERSISTED` column due to it being non-deterministic. I'm also okay with daylight saving time giving me a 23 hour day in spring and a 25 hour day in fall.

On my summary view:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, TmStamp_Local)) AS CalDate,
    MAX(AirTemp_Avg) AS HighTemp,
    MIN(AirTemp_Avg) AS LowTemp,
    AVG(AirTemp_Avg) AS AvgTemp
FROM
    dbo.DL_MAIN_Weather
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, TmStamp_Local))
```

This works, but is *relatively* slow (I'll add more columns to this view eventually). Since historical weather data won't change (unless I need to manually correct a value), it seems a little inefficient to recalculate this table every time I need it.

Any ideas on how to speed it up and possibly index it?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2017.

Comment: sure it's possible to speed it up, indexing might help. But you need to first troubleshoot why is it slow - look at query plan, share index, share statistics io outut, etc.  Without that, it's anyone's guess why it's slow.

Comment: You could store historical data in a summary table, populate in using a scheduled job say, once a month or once a week. That way even if the insertion of the data is relatively slow, the reads would be relatively fast.